# How to include a postgrsql schema name in the namespace when scaffolding from an existing database and place class files into a schema subfolders

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm working with a preexisting postgressql database that has multiple schemas and tables therein. Using Entity Frameworks in a .Net Core web application, I can successfully reverse engineer the database.

My concerns, sooner or later, there will be a table with the same name in different schemas. The classes generated show no signs of the different schemas.

```
CREATE TABLE customers."user" (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name text
);

CREATE TABLE administrators."user" (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name text
);
```

These two tables generate as a User.cs and User1.cs class in the same folder. I would like the name space in the class to include the schema name and the class files to be placed into schema subfolders:

.../Entities/Customers/User.cs

```
namespace DataAccess.Entities.Customers
{
    public partial class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

.../Entities/Administrators/User.cs

```
namespace DataAccess.Entities.Administrators
{
    public partial class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've tried 'Search Path' in the connection string as well as .customers after the database name, nether worked.

Is it possible to generate the classes into different folders and include the schema in the name space of the class?

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick answer to this is to add --schema  to the dotnet ef command line. But one would have to do this for each schema and also set a -o  to make sure the classes go into their own folders.

Comment: FYI https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/3988 tracks improving this.

Comment: Saw that. Thanks.